# 3gp video and AVPlayer in iPhone

Tags: ios, avfoundation, playback, 3gp, avurlasset

I have an iPhone application that plays the videos of Camera Roll using AVPlayer. I have a 3gp video in my iPhone which I am not able to play using AVPlayer but can be played in Photos app.

I would like to achieve these:

1. The videos that are not valid as per AVFoundation classes should not be listed in my views that shows Camera Roll videos using ALAsset Library.
2. Is there any API related to AVURLAsset, AVAssetTrack etc that identifies if the video is playable or not.

I have tried the following:

1. playable property of AVURLAsset says that it is playable.
2. The duration of this videos can be obtained

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?